# Why is my calendar showing years in the future?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple calendar that looks like this:

```
Calendar = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Calendar Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Month Name", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
    "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ),
    "Day", DAY ( [Date] ),
    "Quarter", "Q" & TRUNC ( ( MONTH ( [Date] ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1
)
```

Not sure for what reason but it's showing dates till the 2025:

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: Calendarauto range is based on the dates detected in your data. You either have some future dates, or some dates are screwed up and show as future years. Go through your tables and check all date fields.

Comment: I was playing with forecast. It's me that made bubu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALENDARAUTO() gives a full calendar year for any dates in your whole model. You must have a future date in there somewhere. To suppress the values showing in the slicer, create a measure:

```
Measure = COUNTROWS(your fact table)
```

And add it as a visual filter to the slicer with value > 0.